# celery chord with a chain callback

Tags: python, celery, workflow, chain, chord

I have a complex workflow involving different celery tasks.
I have designed a workflow that involves calling a group in the middle of a chain.
That means, it could be thought as a chain, a chord, and another chain as the chord callback. However, the chord callback would only execute the first task of the chain callback and not the next ones. How can this be achieved? It does work fine if the callback is a group, but this does not fit the logic needed here.

The following sample code never receives / executes `task_h` and `task_i` (ie. last executed task is the first of the chain callback, instead of the entire chain (tasks g, h and i). Hints?

```py
ctask = chain(
    task_a.si(**kwargs),
    task_b.si(**kwargs),
    task_c.si(**kwargs),
    chord(
        [
            task_d.si(**kwargs),
            task_e.si(**kwargs),
            task_f.si(**kwargs),
        ],
        chain(
            task_g.si(**kwargs),
            task_h.si(**kwargs),
            task_i.si(**kwargs),
        ),
    ),
)

[task.set(queue='high_priority') for task in ctask.tasks]
task = ctask.apply_async()
```

```
celery:  {extras = ["redis"], version = "^5.0.5"}
broker:  rabbitmq
backend: redis
```

Comment: If a task in a chain fails to execute, the rest of the chain will not be executed, so I assume task_g() failed...

Comment: Thanks Dejan, but task_g executes fine - the issue is that a chord only takes a callback (ie. one signature or a group) but when passed a chain, it will just understand the first task of the chain as the callback and discard the next ones

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?